# Zshのshell関数の中で自作のmy_appを一度動かしたら、その後my_appやcatやls、パッケージマネージャのコマンドなどが使えなくなるのを改善したい

Tags: shellscript, zsh

移動先のパスを書いたファイルをtempフォルダに生成して、移動先のパスをcatで取ってきてcdするみたいなプログラムを書いています。同じ関数をBashでも書いておりそちらは正常に動作しています。

試している環境は、vscodeのcodespacesでubuntu22.04です。

```
function my_cmd(){
  temp_path="/tmp_path/to/_my_app.$$"
  my_app "${temp_path}"
  path=`cat "${temp_path}"`
  cd "${path}" || return
}
```

`my_cmd`を実行すると一度目はちゃんと動くのですが、それ以降実行すると下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
my_cmd:3: command not found: my_app
my_cmd:4: command not found: cat
```

(まれに`my_cmd:3 permission denied: my_app`となる時もあります)

`my_cmd`実行後、`cd`や`pwd`は実行できますが、パッケージマネージャや`ls`等のコマンドは`command not found` となります。

zshを強制終了して開きなおすと、一度目だけ動いて再度`command not found`を吐くようになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現状の書き方だと、既存の path の内容を上書きしてしまうので、各種コマンドが見つからない状態になってしまうのだと思います。

> ```bash
> path=`cat "${temp_path}"`
> ```

変わりに、例えば以下のような記述で既存の path に追加してみてください。

```
path=(${path} ${temp_path})
```